# Handle Any data type dynamically in Scala

Tags: scala, scalatra

I have a map in Scala returned by a function which is of type `Map[String, Any]`

For example:

```
val map: Map[String, Any] = Map("key1" -> "strVal", "key2" -> List[Map[String, Any]](), "key3" -> Map("k1" -> "v1"))
```

Now the problem is, to work on the value I get corresponding to a key, I've to use `asInstanceOf[]` every time. For eg,

```
val key2Hash = map.getOrElse("key3", Map()).getOrElse("k1", "")
```

throws error because the Map retrieved is of form `Any` and I have to use `asInstanceOf[]` for every situation as belows:

```
val key2Hash = map.getOrElse("key3", Map()).asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]].getOrElse("k1", "")
```

Is there a better way to do it? Or should I not be starting of with `Map[String, Any]` at the first place?

Comment: If there are only two data types you could use an Either[A,B] to represent your data.

Comment: It's best to avoid `Any` if you can. If you can't, you can do pattern matching. It does `isInstanceOf` + `asInstanceOf` behind the scenes, but it's more idiomatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map[String, Any]`? You might as well use python directly!

Joking apart, you can get "nicer" casts syntax using pattern matching:

```
map.get("key3") match {
  case Some(anotherMap: Map[String, String]) => ...
  case _ => ...
}
```